Any user can accept answers on questions with deleted authors
It's possible for any user to accept answers on behalf of a deleted user. I just did so to this post, marking my own answer as accepted.


This isn't possible through the UI, you need to send the HTTP request manually, such as by running the following in your browser console.
await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22240583/vote/1", {
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  "body": `fkey=${fkey.value}`,
  "method": "POST"
}).then(r => r.text());

We've previously seen this message when accept votes were transferred to Community when the question author's account was deleted, but as far as I know that's the only scenario where it's appeared. I guessed that this behaviour might have been related to some experiment with the ability for moderators to accept answers on behalf of deleted answers because I see a "HasAcceptedByModRights" field in the API response to the vote request, but I've otherwise never heard of something like that being implemented or intended, though some users have requested it over the years.

I think it might have been better to report this as a security vulnerability.

Is that capability for moderators documented somewhere?

@nalka I don’t think it was ever actually enabled in the UI, and it might not be new. I see now that the message on the accept button has actually been used for a long time for accepted answers where the question asked was later deleted and the accept vote transferred to Community. I just guessed that this was meant to be a moderator capability because there’s a field in the vote API response named “HasAcceptedByModRights”. Maybe it’s been like this for a long time, I’m not sure

I know that the Stack Overflow for Teams product allows Admins to accept answers on other deactivated users behalf so it's possible (likely?) that the HasAcceptedByModRights came from that code base instead of an intentional experiment on the main site.

@HenryEcker aha, that makes so much more sense! Thanks for sharing that information.

@HenryEcker Don't make your ethical hacker any wiser  ;)

Please report security vulnerabilities through the Reporting Security Vulnerabilities process.

We've deployed a change to mitigate this vulnerability. Echoing the reminder from Makyen, please report suspected security vulnerabilities through the Reporting Security Vulnerabilities process.
